# How can I load a local json file?

Tags: json, security, firefox, local-storage

**Is there a way to configure firefox using about:config to allow local file access (for demo purposes)?**

Specifically using FF12, I need to be able to have local file access to json data. It runs fine on a server, but I'd like to make this demo more portable.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "../_assets/levelschema.json",
            complete: function (data) {
                Levels = data.levels;
                //...
            },
            success: function (data) {                    
                // wont get called b/c files don't have 200 HTTP status
            },
            async: false
        });
```

I've tried setting it to not async=false, but I get a "Access to restricted URI denied" error. This is a security feature. I really need the demo to work offline, without internet access, and I'd prefer the people using it not have to install a web server. I'd also prefer not having to embed all my data in the HTML tags since that data subject to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, JSON requests using AJAX work just fine as long as your data files are down path from your originating HTML file. So I was trying to go up a level to _assets/ directory. The solution is to move _assets into the HTML current directory for access.

You can use AJAX with async=false in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can flip the `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` preference in `about:config`.  But that opens up some security holes; moving your JSON to be in a child directory of the directory the HTML is in is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the JSON file is on your local computer, access it like this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.json"></script>`

You'll have to add that line to your offline project and remove it when it's live, but it's the best way to do it without any server-side assistance. You'll also have to remove your AJAX code for your demo, because it's not going to work on your local computer.

Comment: yeah, I said I didn't want to do this because I have a variable number of json files defined in a schema json. I don't want to manually embed each json, as that makes the CMS pretty useseless =)

Comment: Come to think of it, why are you getting your own JSON files with AJAX? Will they be on a different server from your project when you go live?

Comment: yeah it gets complicated with tradeshows and whatnot. there usually has to be a completely offline version of an online version that is more dynamic...

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't think of anything else that would help with that other than using some server-side code. Maybe you could check to see if you're on your local machine, and add the script tags to the HTML on the fly if you are, like this: `if (location.href.indexOf("localhost") != -1) { /* add script tags */ }` Then in the `else`, you would use your regular AJAX code. Just a thought. Let me know if you come up with something that works.