# Do we need a web server (like Apache) to access a .json file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, webserver

I was trying to read an `info.json` file, using the jQuery API. Please find the code below, which is part of `test.html`.

```
$.getJSON('info.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });
```

The `test.html` file resides on my local machine and when I try to open it in the browser, the Ajax call is not getting triggered and the `info.json` file is not read.

Is it not working because I don't have a web server? Or am I doing anything wrong in the code? (I don't see any errors in the Firebug console though).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need of apache for accessing json file , if you are accessing the local file , the protocol will be file://xxxx , if its through http it will be http: //xxxx

Comment: @AkhilThayyil Are you sure ? That the browser won't thrown a security restrictions error ?

Comment: having a test server is always a good thing.Try http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: @harsha if you are accessing the json file from the same path , then the security execption wont happen , check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760689/how-can-i-load-a-local-json-file

Comment: @AkhilThayyil : That's precisely my point.You have to change the same origin policy manually on the browser.It's not by default!

Comment: @harsha if you are accessing file from same path , then it will work without changing config

Comment: Thanks Akhil and Harsha. Have started using apache web server in the XAMPP package and have placed my files under htdocs folder and tried accessing the files with **localhost/test.html**. everything works as expected :)

Comment: @AkhilThayyil : that did not work for me!But anyway , since the OP has got what he was looking for , lets end this argument ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always have to host your site from where you are making AJAX call. Otherwise it will throw this exception.

```
origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin
```

Host your page on localhost server and I guess everything will work nicely.

Comment: Thanks blunderboy... Yes, it started working after placing under localhost server, i used the xampp package.

Answer (score 1):

While technically you don't need a web server for this, some of the libraries you use to abstract network access may not work with local files and some browsers don't let local files do a lot, so something like [a little test web server for static files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8427954/14955) would be very useful for your development and testing.

Comment: Thanks Thilo, will try out using node.js as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Install a small webserver like http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/
easy to install, and small download ;)

Answer (score 0):

By putting your JSON string into a text file and loading it in a iframe, you can extrapolate the data. (Most browsers can load .txt files in iframes.)

```
var frame = document.createElement("IFRAME"); //Create new iframe
var body = document.body;
frame.onload = function() { //Extrapolate JSON once loaded
  data = JSON.parse(frame.contentDocument.documentElement.innerText); //Loads as a global.
  body.removeChild(frame); //Removes the frame once no longer necessary.
}
frame.style.display = "none"; //Because the frame will have to be appended to the body.
body.appendChild(frame);
frame.src = "your JSON.txt"; //Select source after the onload function is set.
```